# Prove or refute: $A_1,\ldots,A_n\vdash_{CPL} B \iff (A_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge A_n)\vdash_{CPL} B$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Need to prove or refute:

> $A_1, \ldots, A_n \vdash_{\rm CPL} B \iff A_1 \land\dots\land A_n \vdash_{\rm CPL} B$

Since we have $\iff$ operator, we have to deal with to directions.
Let's begin from the LTR-direction.
We have:

> $A_1, \ldots, A_n \vdash_{\rm CPL} B$

Need to prove:

> $A_1 \land\dots\land A_n \vdash_{\rm CPL} B$

But how to continue with this direction? What exactly can we assume from the left part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A1 , … , An (⊢CPL) B, then if each member of {A1, ..., An} is true, then so is B (by soundness).  Consequently, if each member of {A1, ..., An} is true, then so is A1 ^ ... ^ An.  B is true also.  Since all truths imply each other, this implies that A1 ^ ...^ An (⊢CPL) B is true also (by completeness).  Therefore, A1 , … , An (⊢CPL) B implies that A1 ^ ...^ An (⊢CPL) B.